# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint, Cannot insert duplicate key (MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below:

```
|Bookname|BDate|Description
```

and Bookname is my Primary Key
I need to read a file regularly to update my table. I have writen a Stored Procedure to update the file as below:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateMyTable] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SourceTable AS DVTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    MERGE dbo.MyTarget AS T
    USING @SourceTable AS S ON (T.BookName=S.BookName)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target
    THEN INSERT(BookName,BDate,Description) 
    VALUES(S.BookName,S.BDate,S.Description)
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET T.BookName=S.BookName,T.BDate=S.BDate,T.Description=S.Description;

END
```

There is a problem that inside the text file some records repeated twice, so the merge function inserts the file at first and for the second time throw exception: [Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint]

I was wondering if there is any way to set MERGE to ignore it if find that Bookname for the second time.

Comment: I don't know if this would solve, but in the `WHEN MATCHED` you can remove the `T.BookName = S.BookName` from `SET`, because those two values will be already the same

Comment: Is there a possibility that there can be multiple books with same name but different dates? if so you can try creating a composite primary key (name,date).

Comment: No in my case we cannot have two different book with same name, it is a mistake in the source file and I should just ignore it.

Comment: @MehrdadBabaki If that is the case you can just copy distinct records from the source table into another temp table and use that in the merge statement. is that possible?

Comment: I think your `source table` has two rows with the same `BookName` that doesn't exist in `Target table`.

Comment: @Coder1991 There are some different solutions, but first, I want to see if there is any solution to keep Merge

Comment: @TriV Yes, I know that, my question is how tell Merge function to ignore the second one

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: updating the matching column in the `when matched` part doesn't make much sense (Oracle wouldn't even allow that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `source table` has two rows with the same `BookName` that doesn't exist in `Target table`, you could use `CTE` like that

```
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT st.* , 
          row_number() over(PARTITION BY st.BookName ORDER BY BookDate desc)  as Rn 
   FROM @SourceTable st
)
MERGE dbo.MyTarget AS T
USING (SELECT * FROM temp t WHERE Rn = 1) AS S ON (T.BookName=S.BookName)
............
```

Answer (score 2):

Before the merge, try deleting the duplicate records from the table @SourceTable  based on BDate. The below query will delete the bookname with lower booking date and keep the highest booking date for that Book so you can have unique BookName.

```
;with cte (BookName,BDate,Description,RowNum)AS
(

Select BookName,BDate,Description,Row_number() over(partition by BookName  order by BDate desc)
 from @SourceTable
)
delete from cte where rownum>1
```

Comment: Your answer was partially correct, the only issue was after deleting from cte, the CTE would be disappeared. Thanks