# SQL Server insert query avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert into TableA from TableB and avoiding duplicates, I tried the below it gives an error:

> Violation of Primary Key constraint 'PK_TableA'. Cannot insert duplicate key ...

```
 insert  into TableA (DataField, TitleId, ClassId, ValueOrder, StrValue)
    select 'Somtext',[title_id],'-1', '1', 
          [reference_text]
    from TableB
    where TableB.SomeColumn ='sometext 2014'



TableA
Title_id  reference_text
1234       ABCD   
1487       XFRE
1434       DERE

TableB
DataField  TitleId  ClassId  ValueOrder  StrValue
```

Now the Problem here is Data already exists in `TableB`. I need to avoid when `TableA.Tile_id = TableB.TitleId`, when this matches.

Comment: So how do you want to handle it?  Don't insert?  Insert a different `Title_ID`, if so how is that decided?

Comment: So what is that constraint? That should tell you what you need to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint, Cannot insert duplicate key (MS SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447854/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `where not exists`

```
insert  into TableA (DataField, TitleId, ClassId, ValueOrder, StrValue)
select 'Somtext',[title_id],'-1', '1', 
       [reference_text]
from TableB
where TableB.SomeColumn ='sometext 2014'
and not exists (select 1 from TableA ta where ta.TitleID = TableB.title_id)
```

Comment: it says invalid object name TableA in the last line

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, you could do a merge and when matched then (delete/update/insert).

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `NOT IN` to the `WHERE`-clause like this should work:

```
WHERE TableB.SomeColumn ='sometext 2014'
AND TableB.TitleId NOT IN (SELECT Tile_Id FROM TableA)
```